# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED error

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose, frontend

I am writing an application. I write .net for the backend and Angular for the frontend. When dockering, I put my frontend application inside nginx. Dockerfile is like this

```
FROM node:20.10-alpine AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json .
RUN npm install
RUN npx ngcc --properties es2023 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points
COPY . .
RUN npm run build --prod

FROM nginx:stable
COPY --from=build /app/dist/librari-fy/ /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

nginx.conf is as follows:

```
worker_processes 1;


events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name http://backend:80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html/browser;
        index index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;


        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
        gzip_min_length   256;
        gzip_vary         on;
        gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
        gzip_comp_level   9;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://localhost:4200' always;
        }
    }
}
```

Docker-compose file :

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:16-alpine
    container_name: postgredatabase
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: UArA0CGd5y1g5sE7U0OH
      POSTGRES_USER: libraryadmin
      POSTGRES_DB: Library
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app_internal_network
    healthcheck:
      test: pg_isready
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 60s
      retries: 5
      start_period: 80s 
    
  backend:
    image: sahinyakici/librarybackend:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: backend
    depends_on:
      postgres:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - app_internal_network
    ports:
      - "8080:80"

  frontend:
    container_name: librarify
    image: sahinyakici/librarify:latest
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - app_internal_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
    expose:
      - 80

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  app_internal_network:
    driver: bridge
```

The applications run successfully, but I get the following error in the console in the website: "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". If I go into the UI container and try with curl, I can fetch data from the backend. What do you think is the problem?

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJ63S.png)
[Error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjPu7.png) [Error3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccUFf.png)

I tried using Curl from within the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frontend code is executed client side, meaning the browser processes the code and not the NGINX web server. When you request your Frontend container, the NGINX server returns the HTML, CSS and Javascript files of your website, which are interpreted by browser.

Therefore you're browser, and by extend your computer, will be the one making requesting the backend API. So the backend URL configured within the frontend should be `http://localhost:8080` rather than `http://backend`

Your NGINX server should only be serving the Frontend files. Fix the `server_name` to `localhost` and fix the Backend URL within your Frontend code to `http://localhost:8080`

Comment: I changed my ngingx.conf file like this: "server_name http://localhost:8080;" but the problem is still same.

Comment: Change it to `localhost` and most importantly, what's the Backend URL you configured in your Frontend code ?

Comment: for example: "private apiUrl: string = 'http://backend:80/api/'books/getall;"

Comment: Change the host to `localhost:8080`.

Comment: like this "http://localhost:8080/api/books/getall" right?

Comment: Yes :) Do it for every `apiUrl`, rebuild your Docker image and it should be fine.

Comment: Good news, at least I get a different error :) I added it as Error 2.

Comment: Nice, so we managed to get the frontend page + make backend requests. Can you chech the backend container for any logs ?

Comment: Logs said "2023-12-10 19:23:05 [16:23:05 INF] HTTP GET /api/Genres/GetAll responded 200 in 4.1075 ms
2023-12-10 19:23:05 [16:23:05 INF] HTTP GET /api/books/getall responded 200 in 0.5491 ms"

Comment: frontend logs " 2023-12-10 19:24:00 192.168.176.1 - - [10/Dec/2023:16:24:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36""

Comment: Can you try using a different browser ?

Comment: I tried it and got different results. I added the errors I received in Brave and Opera as Error3.

Comment: You're getting CORS error, are you familiar with these ? Basically you need to tell your backend that it can be requested using URL `localhost:8080`' I'll let you make research on how to implement it using .NET since i'm not very familiar with it :)

Comment: Even your help this much meant a lot to me. I thought I had cleared this topic. I will investigate this issue now. Thank you very much again for everything :)

Comment: Always a pleasure ! ;)